# ASHX HTTP Handlers and forms authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net, ashx

I have an ashx handler that I use to upload files from a flex page. I have been unable to extend forms authentication to protect the ashx file. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can always check `context.Request.IsAuthenticated` in your .ashx file. ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx))

Comment: I already tried that. A login page leads to a test page that invokes the handler. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could ways add a web.config file in the same directory as the ashx file with the following contents (i think):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>

    <system.web>

      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>

    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: It does deny access to the ashx. Denies it too well. The code in ashx can't seem to detect if someone is authenticated or not.

Comment: Are you authenticating correctly? perhaps after you have logged in you are having a cookie type issue so that you were authenticated but have quickly lost that info?-- that setting in the web.config should allow authenticated users...